# Android View Gone

Tags: android

New to andriod and trying to set view.GONE based on shared preferences. However it's not gone! What did i break?!

EDIT
So, after testing the underling issue was that the settings weren't being done correctly... So now that that is fixed lets try again. He'res my onCreate... When i remove the textview temp code it works fine and shows the change in pref via the toast, however when the code it there the app crashes.

```
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SharedPreferences mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment      

            Boolean symptothermal = mPreferences.getBoolean("symptothermal", true);

            if (!symptothermal) {
                Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Hello toast 1!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Hello toast 2!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            if (!symptothermal) {
                TextView temp = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.temp);
                temp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
```

He're the XML FYI:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.23" >

        <!-- Date Text -->
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/dateselected"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/pickdate"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="date" />

        <!-- DatePicker button -->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pickdate"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/dateselected"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dateselected"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_datepicker"
            android:text="@string/date" />

        <!-- Temp Label -->
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/temp"
            android:layout_width="192dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/pickdate"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="@string/temp"
            android:clickable="false" 
            android:cursorVisible="false" 
            android:focusable="false" 
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false" 
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
        </EditText>

         <!-- Temp field -->
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/tempvalue"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/pickdate"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dateselected"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Notes Field -->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/chartingnote"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.58"
        android:ems="20"
        android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/hintNote"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

    <!-- Update Button -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/chartingupdate"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/charting_update" />

</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT @ daniel_c05:

```
        package com.projectcaruso.naturalfamilyplaning;

        import com.projectcaruso.naturalfamilyplanning.R;

        import android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.SharedPreferences;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
        import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.DatePicker;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        public class ChartingFragment extends Fragment implements OnDateSetListener {
            SharedPreferences mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
            Boolean symptothermal = mPreferences.getBoolean("symptothermal", true);

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }    

            public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
                DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
                newFragment.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


                if (!symptothermal) {
                    Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Hello toast 1!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Hello toast 2!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }



            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                //Inflate a view
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_charting, null);
                //now you can initialize the TextView
                //notice how we don't call getView()? :P
                TextView temp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.temp);
                if (!symptothermal) {
                //Hide the view if necessary
                        temp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                return view;
               }


        }
```

Logs:

```
    05-08 14:10:55.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22900): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    05-08 14:10:55.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22900): java.lang.NullPointerException
    05-08 14:10:55.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22900):    at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(PreferenceManager.java:371)
    05-08 14:10:55.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22900):    at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:366)
    05-08 14:10:55.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22900):    at com.projectcaruso.naturalfamilyplaning.ChartingFragment.<init>(ChartingFragment.java:21)
    05-08 14:10:55.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22900):    at com.projectcaruso.naturalfamilyplaning.MenuFragment.onListItemClick(MenuFragment.java:36)
    05-08 14:10:55.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22900):    at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:58)
    05-08 14:10:55.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22900):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
    05-08 14:10:55.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22900):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
    05-08 14:10:55.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22900):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
    05-08 14:10:55.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22900):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
    05-08 14:10:55.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22900):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    05-08 14:10:55.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22900):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    05-08 14:10:55.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22900):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    05-08 14:10:55.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22900):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    05-08 14:10:55.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22900):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    05-08 14:10:55.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22900):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    05-08 14:10:55.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22900):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    05-08 14:10:55.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22900):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    05-08 14:10:55.042: E/AndroidRuntime(22900):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Is your `textview` i.e. `temp` is inside `fragment_charting` layout ?

Comment: @jcaruso did you test if your if statement returns the correct value?

Comment: I just tested it and within the on create the symptothermal boolean is always true. So somehow that key isn't returning it's value. Its a SwitchPreference aren't they Boolean?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: No i cannot find the problem or am missing something where i cannot get preferences that are set up...

Comment: See new edit with the updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I understand, you are using a Fragment for this code.

Therefore, be aware that the life-cycle of a Fragment differs from that of an activity. During `onCreate` you **cannot** manipulate UI elements on a Fragment.

You use this:

```
 if (!symptothermal) {
            TextView temp = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.temp);
            temp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

Let's change it a bit,

**Step One**: Change `Boolean symptothermal` to be a instance variable, and not an inner variable of `onCreate`. Therefore, making it available during the different lifecycles.

**Step Two**: Keep the same code for `onCreate`, except the fact that you don't call the code that changes the TextView visibility, we'll move that somewhere else.

**Step Three**: Override onCreateView instead.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Inflate a view
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
    //now you can initialize the TextView
    //notice how we don't call getView()? :P
    TextView temp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.temp);
    if (!symptothermal) {
    //Hide the view if necessary
            temp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    return view;
   }
```

That should work well.

**EDIT**

So I noticed you did this:

```
SharedPreferences mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
Boolean symptothermal = mPreferences.getBoolean("symptothermal", true);
```

And that is the problem, you are calling getDefaultSharedPreferences outside any of the lifecycles and that's why it fails.

See this:

```
public class ChartingFragment extends Fragment implements OnDateSetListener {
//Don't initialize the instance variables yet
   SharedPreferences mPreferences;
   Boolean symptothermal;

@Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     //Here's a good moment to initialize
    mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    symptothermal = mPreferences.getBoolean("symptothermal", true);

        if (!symptothermal) {
            Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Hello toast 1!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Hello toast 2!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Daniel see the new edit where i posted the full code... when i run this it crashes when i got to this fragment. Did i miss something?

Comment: What is the error in the logs? Also, make sure that if there's any line pointed in the log, you tell us what line of code that is.

Comment: Your the man! I don't know what i woulda done, this has been at me for 2 days now. I'd vote up it if i had one more rep!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set the view to gone before it is even created, your onCreateView hasn't returned anything yet, but then after the if it goes and completes your `inflater.inflate` and returns the view. You should perform that check within the `onStart` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

`onCreateView()` is used for creating the view. When `onCreateView` has returned, the view is created. There is a method `onViewCreated` that is used to modify the view.

more info in the documentation:
[Fragment#onViewCreated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewCreated%28android.view.View,%20android.os.Bundle%29)

Answer (score 0):

You'll never set the TextView's visibility to GONE because your `if` statement is wrong: you **set** a value instead of **checking** it. You should do:

```
if (symptothermal == false)
```

or

```
if (!symptothermal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Observing your `onCreate()` there are some things which doesn't make any sense to me.

Using `Boolean symptothermal = preferences.getBoolean("symptothermal", true);` will always return `true`. You setted `true` as default value and I don't see any part of your code where variable `symptothermal` is set to `false`, that mean your if statement will never be executed. Have you tried to to make `if(symptothermal)` instead of? (Just make sure it will work with the default value).

Furthermore, `TextView temp = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.temp);` will crash your app with a `ClassCastException`! Why? Because your view with temp id is not a `TextView` but an `EditText`.

Let me know of your progress.

Comment: Ok help me make sense of it... the Boolean, the  preferences.getBoolean return the preference, if not defined default it to true. Correct?

Comment: @jcaruso, Exactly. The boolean value passed on `getBoolean()` is the default value. In your case `true` will be returned and thats why your if doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, this is `getBoolean` behaviour.

Comment: Ok i'm missing something, wouldn't getBoolean("symptothermal", true) return the value of the symptothermal preference key?

Comment: Yes, but only if there is a `setBoolean()` before! If not, there is no `symptothermal` variable defined on the preference file and will always be returned a `true` value.

Comment: `getBoolean("symptothermal", true)` do this: look in SharedPrefs if there is an item called "symptothermal". If the item exists it returns the boolean value (or throws an Exception if value isn't a boolean). But if the item doesn't exists it returns the second parameter, which is `true`

Comment: ok so i'm still not sure i understand ya'll because with the corrected code it still shows up true or false depending on what the pref is.