# Android Prefererences

Tags: android

I'm coming to think my problem is with my preferences not being done correctly is why i cannot access tem. Here is My preferences:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <PreferenceCategory 
        android:title="@string/pref_user_profile" 
        android:textSize="20px"
        android:layout="@layout/pref_layout">

        <SwitchPreference 
                android:title="@+string/pref_frequency"
                android:summary="@+string/pref_frequency_summary"
                android:key="frequency" 
                android:defaultValue="true"
            android:layout="@layout/pref_layout"/>

        <SwitchPreference 
                android:title="@+string/pref_time"
                android:summary="@+string/pref_time_summary"
                android:key="time"
                android:defaultValue="true"
            android:layout="@layout/pref_layout"/>

        <SwitchPreference  
                android:title="@+string/pref_symptothermal"
                android:summary="@+string/pref_symptothermal_summary"
                android:key="symptothermal"
                android:defaultValue="true"
                android:layout="@layout/pref_layout"/>

        <SwitchPreference 
                android:title="@+string/pref_cervical_mucus"
                android:summary="@+string/pref_cervical_mucus_summary"
                android:key="cervical_mucus"
                android:defaultValue="true"
            android:layout="@layout/pref_layout"/>    

        <SwitchPreference 
                android:title="@+string/pref_mucus_stamps"
                android:summary="@+string/pref_mucus_stamps_summary"
                android:key="mucus_stamps"
                android:defaultValue="true"
            android:layout="@layout/pref_layout"/>

        <SwitchPreference 
                android:title="@+string/pref_fertile_infertile"
                android:summary="@+string/pref_fertile_infertile_summary"
                android:key="fertile_infertil" 
                android:defaultValue="true"
            android:layout="@layout/pref_layout"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Java:

```
package com.projectcaruso.naturalfamilyplaning;

import com.projectcaruso.naturalfamilyplanning.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class UserSettingActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

    }
}
```

Here is my call to the settings menu:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        final int RESULT_SETTINGS = 1;

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.projectcaruso:
            Util.goToGitHub(this);
            return true;
        case R.id.about:
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(R.string.about)
            .setMessage(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.about_msg)))
            .show();
            break;
        case R.id.licenses:
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(R.string.licenses)
            .setMessage(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.license_detail)))
            .show();
            break;
        case R.id.contact:
            break;
        case R.id.settings:
            Intent j = new Intent(this, UserSettingActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(j, RESULT_SETTINGS);
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.settings, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

So any help would be appreciated! I'm trying to access these preferences but cannot. It seems to be saving them just fine. I am able to test and run the code, change the pref's and it saves their state. However when i try to access them i cannot... Here's the code i used to try and access them:

EDIT:
I've changed it to call as the following and no matter the setting it is still the "Hello toast 2!"
            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                SharedPreferences preferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("UserSettingActivity",0);
                // Inflate the layout for this fragment

```
            Boolean symptothermal = preferences.getBoolean("symptothermal", true);

            if (!symptothermal) {
                Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Hello toast 1!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Hello toast 2!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            if (!symptothermal) {
                TextView temp = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.temp);
                temp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is how you are trying to access them.

You use this line:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref",0);
```

When to access the preferences that are stored through a PreferenceActivity you should call the default preferences.

```
SharedPreferences mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

That is it.

**Edit**

If you are making a call to `getDefaultSharedPreferences()` from a Fragment, you simply need to change the value you pass as parameter. `this` in the above example is a context, to call this from the Fragment, do the following:

```
SharedPreferences mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
```

Comment: getDefaultSharedPreferences errors inside of a fragment... What alternative is there for that?

Comment: It doesn't error, you just need to pass getActivity() instead of 'this'

Comment: I was actually working on a problem with my view.gone if your up for one more... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427450/android-view-gone

Answer (score 0):

Probably you trying to read prefs from a different file.
Add `getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName("pref");` to `UserSettingActivity` and see if it will help

Comment: Let me throw a toast into it to test it... hang on

Comment: Thanks for your help, though the above post fixed it your help was invaluable!